How can I access FDA warning letter data?
I am currently trying to access the FDA warning letter database in order to gather data on which CFR regulations are the most common amongst medical device warning letters.
I am not really experienced in webscraping but the issue I had was that using BeatifulSoup could only access the first 10 warning letters of the website and not all that are on the website.
So then I tried using the OpenFDA website. However the data for Medical Devices seems to be focused around recalls and not warning letters.
Does anybody have an idea on how to approach this?
Thank you already for your help :D

Thank you for reaching out. openFDA does not currently have an endpoint for warning letters, and as such this isn't an openFDA question.
Note: I'm a part of openFDA team.
